# MS Access: Query group by, but show all fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of items ordered. 
Table fields: PONumber, OrderDate, itemNumber, Description, Cost

Since I can have an item ordered multiple times at different dates, I want to return the just the most recent date, but still include all the fields.

**Table**

```
PONumber    OrderDate   itemNumber  Description Cost
123         01/01/2016  A235        Bolt        1.13
142         02/22/2016  A235        Blot        2.10
166         03/01/2016  A444        Screw       1.22
411
```

**Return**

```
PONumber    OrderDate   itemNumber  Description Cost
142         02/22/2016  A235        Blot        2.10
166         03/01/2016  A444        Screw       1.22
```

I have tried a total query, but I have to remove the Cost field or else it displays all the records and I need to display the cost.

```
SELECT PONumber, Max(OrderDate), itemNumber, Description, Cost
FROM tblItemsOrdered
GROUP BY PONumber, OrderDate, itemNumber, Description, Cost;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the latest order date for each item in subquery and join it with the original table like this:

```
select t1.*
from tblItemsOrdered t1
inner join (
    SELECT itemNumber, Max(OrderDate) as Max_OrderDate
    FROM tblItemsOrdered
    GROUP BY itemNumber
) t2 on t1.itemNumber = t2.itemNumber
and t1.OrderDate = t2.Max_OrderDate;
```

Note that this will return multiple rows for same itemNumber in case all those rows have latest orderDate.

#### EDIT:

```
select t1.*
from tblItemsOrdered t1
inner join (
    select t1.itemNumber, t1.OrderDate, max(t1.PONumber) as max_PONumber
    from tblItemsOrdered t1
    inner join (
        SELECT itemNumber, Max(OrderDate) as Max_OrderDate
        FROM tblItemsOrdered
        GROUP BY itemNumber
    ) t2 on t1.itemNumber = t2.itemNumber
    and t1.OrderDate = t2.Max_OrderDate
    group by t1.itemNumber, t1.OrderDate
) t2 on t1.itemNumber = t2.itemNumber
and t1.PONumber = t2.max_PONumber
and t1.OrderDate = t2.OrderDate;
```

or if PONumber is unique:

```
select t1.*
from tblItemsOrdered t1
inner join (
    select t1.itemNumber, max(t1.PONumber) as max_PONumber
    from tblItemsOrdered t1
    inner join (
        SELECT itemNumber, Max(OrderDate) as Max_OrderDate
        FROM tblItemsOrdered
        GROUP BY itemNumber
    ) t2 on t1.itemNumber = t2.itemNumber
    and t1.OrderDate = t2.Max_OrderDate
    group by t1.itemNumber
) t2 on t1.itemNumber = t2.itemNumber
and t1.PONumber = t2.max_PONumber;
```

Comment: Does this query work in MS Access? It's somewhat limited from my experience?

Comment: I think it should work fine. Also, why don't you try and see it works?

Comment: Last i tried aliases did not work in MS Access 2016, I had to actually write out each tableName.columnName. But maybe I did something wrong...?

Comment: looks like the code snippet might be missing `FROM tblItemsOrdered t2` on the inner join subquery.

Comment: Ah, I see the alias/reference now after the subquery.

Comment: I noticed that my table has a few records where the PONumber is different but have the same OrderDate. This would return both. In this Case I would want just the largest PONumber. I tried adding Max(PONumber) in the subquery, but it did nothing.

Comment: Might need to do a TOP 1/ORDER BY PONumber DESC to get the largest PONumber.

Comment: Originally tried Top 1 in the inner query with max(PONumber) and only returned 1 record for the whole query. If I don't use the max() function, Access returns the error message: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'PONumber' as part of an aggregate function."

Comment: My unique field in this example is the itemNumber, so it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `group by`.  You want all the columns, so think `where`, to do filtering:

```
select o.*
from tblItemsOrdered as o
where o.OrderDate = (select max(o2.OrderDate)
                     from tblItemsOrdered as o2
                     where o2.itemNumber = o.itemNumber
                    );
```

Note:  If the item is ordered multiple times on the most recent date, then this will return all the rows.

Comment: I don't think aliases works in MS Access either, but I might be wrong

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks!